# Combining "LIKE" and "IN" for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-like

Is it possible to combine `LIKE` and `IN` in a SQL Server-Query?

So, that this query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE IN ('Text%', 'Link%', 'Hello%', '%World%')
```

Finds any of these possible matches:

```
Text, Textasd, Text hello, Link2, Linkomg, HelloWorld, ThatWorldBusiness
```

etc...

Comment: Have a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74220539/12930883, it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 428, accepted):

Effectively, the IN statement creates a series of OR statements... so

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Is effectively

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 1 OR column = 2 OR column = 3
```

And sadly, that is the route you'll have to take with your LIKE statements

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column LIKE 'Text%' OR column LIKE 'Hello%' OR column LIKE 'That%'
```

Comment: is this the only available syntax?

Comment: Just a note: the last query also works in oracle(11g)

Comment: I was looking for regex example inside the like but this will do for now !

Comment: You could use build dynamic SQL statement, stacking the OR's. To improve security, should use parameter binding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943202/how-to-late-parameter-bind-to-dynamic-sql-statement-in-a-stored-procedure

Comment: Last query will not work if IN clause statement returns indefinite number of values.

Comment: Hey, so I know it's been 4063 days since you posted this answer but here's my two cents.
This
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (1, 2, 3)
Is not like this
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 1 OR column = 2 OR column = 3
Because if you do this:
SELECT * FROM table Where column1 = value1 AND column2 = value 2 or column2 = value 22 .. etc
Does not give the same results as this
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = value1  and column2 IN (1, 2, 3).

Comment: So, if we used LIKE we would have  to repeat "column LIKE ... or column LIKE...". I wonder anyways to make it short.

Comment: @Fenton hi, this query is working but I have thousands of data that need to check in like, so there will too many " OR LIKE" in query. So is there any query that can combine all "OR LIKE". I have tried some queries but not working.

Comment: Thanks! So, we can not combine a bunch of LIKE statments as LIKE (patt1, patt2, ...etc)?

Answer (score 324):

I know this is old but I got a kind of working solution

```
SELECT Tbla.* FROM Tbla
INNER JOIN Tblb ON
Tblb.col1 Like '%'+Tbla.Col2+'%'
```

You can expand it further with your where clause etc.
I only answered this because this is what I was looking for and I had to figure out a way of doing it.

Comment: @lloydz1 this isn't the original question though which has a column of values created on the fly. You are doing this on two tables.

Comment: Does not accurately address the question. This works with a standard column from another table, not a manually curated list of words.

Comment: anyway to flag which value it is like?

Comment: Doesn't address the question !

Comment: This can get duplicate results if col1 match the condition for diferent like values

Comment: Of course it answers the question - you can do with a table everything you can do with a list, but not vice versa hence THIS is the general solution

Comment: Doesn't address question exactly, however you could try substrings of `Tbla.Col2`.

Comment: I agree with @GerasimosR.  Its trivial to use to an in line table statement with a list (`SELECT * FROM VALUE ('%patern1%', pat%ern%2') AS TableAlias(Col1)`) instead of a table.

Comment: worked like a charm! 
For postgresql folks , use this :- 
(on er.company_name ilike '%'||db."Company"||'%')

Comment: Try Tblb.col1 Like '%'||Tbla.Col2||'%' if "+" doesn't work for you

Comment: This link seems to have the correct answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/170579/select-multiple-values-in-like-operator

Comment: This solution was half the solution to my problem. The other half was [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows). So, in a list of values separated by a character, a simple solution is this:



`SELECT * FROM table INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(ISNULL('Text,Link,Hello,World',''), ',') t2 ON column Like '%' + isnull(t2.value,column)+'%'`

Comment: @JamieMarshall can you post a complete, trivial example?

Comment: @Evan, try this, but I haven't tested it:  `SELECT Tbla.* FROM Tbla
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT Col1 
 FROM VALUE ('%patern1%', 'pat%ern%2') AS TableAlias(Col1)
) AS Tblb
ON Tblb.col1 Like '%'+Tbla.Col2+'%'`

Comment: The inner join with the literal table approach here is a good solution. I have a SQLite DB in front of me, so please translate to SQL Server or your db of choice:

`select distinct n.* from notes n
inner join(values ('git'), ('golang'), ('ruby')) v
on n.tag like '%' || v.column1 || '%';`

Comment: This is an excellent solution. Although some are complaining (I don't know why) that it doesn't answer the OP, I believe it does. When I searched on this solution, I used keywords IN and LIKE which took me to this thread. The table-based solution combines the concept of using LIKE on a list of values. Whether that list uses IN, a hard-coded list of OR statements or the far more elegant and dynamic table-based solution should not matter. This solution steered me away from using LIKE and IN into a far better table-based solution.

Answer (score 139):

One other option would be to use something like this

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    table t INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  'Text%' Col
            UNION SELECT 'Link%'
            UNION SELECT 'Hello%'
            UNION SELECT '%World%'
        ) List ON t.COLUMN LIKE List.Col
```

Comment: @astander: That's what I thought of.

Comment: This is the closest to the spirit of the question, so +1

Comment: Yes this is the answer that i was looking for
Thank you

Comment: The problem with this solution is if the text column contains text that would find more than one match. For example if your text was 'Hello World' it would find two matches and create an extra row in the results. The first line should be `SELECT DISTINCT t.*` to avoid this happening.

Comment: How is this better, faster or simpler than using multiple LIKE conditions connected with OR?

Answer (score 25):

No, you will have to use `OR` to combine your `LIKE` statements:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   table
WHERE 
   column LIKE 'Text%' OR 
   column LIKE 'Link%' OR 
   column LIKE 'Hello%' OR
   column LIKE '%World%'
```

Have you looked at [Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Answer (score 7):

No, MSSQL doesn't allow such queries. You should use `col LIKE '...' OR col LIKE '...'` etc.