# How to pass the multiple search patterns to sql statement using WHERE IN clause

Tags: sql

Am having the table with below data,

```
  +----------+---------+
  | Country  | Product |
  +----------+---------+
  | Poland   | Lyca    |
  | USA      | Lyca    |
  | UK       | GT      |
  | Spain    | GT      |
  | Swiss    | Lyca    |
  | Portugal | GT      |
  +----------+---------+
```

From the above table, I am trying to fetch the data using the query which is given below,

```
 Select Country,Product from tab where Country in ('%pai%','%U%')
```

Query was executing but i am getting the empty resuls. So, kindly confirm me, whether the above query is valid or not.

Comment: Your `IN` condition will compare the country value to the listed string, that the reason of your empty result (the `%` character is used as substitution only for `LIKE` condition)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865353/combining-like-and-in-for-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

Use `like` and `or`:

```
Select Country,Product
from tab
where Country like '%pai%' or
      Country like '%U%';
```

Comment: I don't see another solution to get the expected result... +1

Answer (score 0):

Get your patterns into a separate table:

```
PATTERNTABLE
SessionKey     Pattern  
----------     -------
abc123         %pai%
abc123         %U%
```

and then join to it:

```
SELECT Country, Product
FROM Tab t
INNER JOIN PatternTable pt ON pt.SessionKey= @SessionKey 
     and t.Country LIKE pt.Pattern
```

The trick is in how that pattern table is populated.