# SQL query using LIKE operators for multi-valued parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset that has two fields **Main_Activity** and **Requesting_Activity**

Sample dataset"

```
Main_activity    Reuesting_Activity
-------------    ------------------
Act1             Act1,Act1a,Act2,Act3
Act2             Act1a,Act3,Act5
Act3             Act1,Act3,Act4
Act4             Act2,Act4,Act5
```

When I use the SQL query and pass **Act1** as parameter **(@mainActivity)** for the dataset

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Main_Activity,
    Requesting_Activity
FROM Activity_table
WHERE Requesting_Activity LIKE ''+ (@mainActivity) +'' OR Requesting_Activity LIKE ''+ (@mainActivity) +',%' OR Requesting_Activity LIKE '%,'+ (@mainActivity) +',%' OR Requesting_Activity LIKE '%,'+ (@mainActivity) +''
```

I get the expected output

```
Act1
Act3
```

The problem is when I make the parameter as multi-select, I am getting error.
How do I resolve it? How to use "LIKE and "IN" operator in same query?

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865353/combining-like-and-in-for-sql-server
its already a duplicate

Comment: I already had a look at that post, but there the values to be matched are  static. In my question it is dynamic.

Comment: @damseldeebi your problem is not in SSRS, but in your table design. Multivalue fields are wrong! You are trying to solve a problem in SSRS, when you just need to redesign your table(s).

Comment: Please, provide error, which you get. Please describe the query logic. 

If you need a Requesting_Activity, which contain @mainActivity, why  don't you use simple variant: 
 Requesting_Activity LIKE '%'+ (@mainActivity) +'%' ?

Comment: @mordack550 My table contains thousands of records and hundreds of fields, if I normalize the database to avoid multi-value fields then I end up in having few thousand more records. So I can't change the table design

Comment: @AndreyDavydenko as you can see, I used that and got the output. But it takes only "single parameter".. from my SSRS report, I want to have the parameter to allow multiple values..

Comment: @damseldeebi I'm sorry, but you are doing it completely wrong. Why do you even care about number of rows, when you are spending A LOT of processing power on LIKEs on multi value fields?? Are you short of hard drive space? Few thousand more records? That's nothing for almost any DMBS, even less on engines like SQL Server that can handle datawarehouses with tables with 30+millions records.

Comment: @damseldeebi you are facing the X-Y problem. You are trying to solve "How to retrieve the rows I want" when the only thing your should care about is "How to correctly design a relational database". Multivalues field in a relational database are **wrong**. Always, no exception.

Comment: @mordack550 yeah I get your point... but that is how the database is designed and I dont have the permissions to change it

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Why did the database end up like that? You don't have any multivalued fields, you only have a text field that you are trying to use as if it were multivalued. This isn't denormalization, you broke even the 1st NF. Essentially, you trapped yourself in a corner. The only efficient way left is to use full text search, ie the FREETEXT  and CONTAINS functions, not LIKE

Comment: A much less performant alternative do what the duplicate proposes, only put the values (with `%` prefix and suffix)in a TVP, then do a join of the two tables with `ON Requesting_Activity LIKE @values.Activity`. Performance will still be bad (no indexes after all) but at least you won't have to type that much

Answer (score 1):

your where clause is full of redundancies

```
WHERE Requesting_Activity LIKE '%'+ (@mainActivity) +'%'
```