# SQL Server 2008 R2: Prepare dynamic WILDCARD

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, wildcard

I have the following table `Test_01` with two columns namely `Cola` and `Colb`.

I have a situation were I need to use `LIKE` with `IN` for multiple values.

**Table**:

```
SELECT * FROM Test_01;

Cola    Colb 
------------
1       A
11      B
22      C
```

**Example**:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(max) = 'A,B,C'
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max) = ''
```

**My bad try**: Which does not works

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * from test_01 
        WHERE Colb LIKE IN (''%'+REPLACE(@a,',','%'',''%')+'%'')';
PRINT(@sql);
```

Finally I came to know that I need to prepare a `LIKE` with `OR` condition by referring [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865353/combining-like-and-in-for-sql-server).

How to prepare a dynamic WILDCARD as shown it below?

```
SELECT * FROM Test_01
WHERE 
Colb LIKE '%A%' OR 
Colb LIKE '%B%' OR 
Colb LIKE '%C%' ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a table variable to parse variable @a values and stored them as rows.
Check using inner join between main table test_01 and table variable with like to see if any matching records.

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(max) = 'A,B,C';

declare @tablevariable table
(
colb varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO @tablevariable
SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@a, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
    ) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);


select tb1.* from test_01 tb1 inner join @tablevariable tb2
on tb1.colb like '%'+tb2.colb+'%'
```