# how can i use % in an "in" statement SQL

Tags: sql, wildcard

I'm trying to say if the event has '%webinar%','%network%' in the name include it "if" the date is after the 01-04-2015. I cant use "or" on a separate line as it ignores the date. Any help appreciated.

```
select 
    ,fsa.eventid
    ,sev.EventStart
    from
    event sev
    on 
    sev.eventId = fsa.eventid
    where sev.SNAP_EventStart >= '2015-04-01'
    and eventidname in ('%webinar%','%network%')
```

Comment: you can use `or` if you place the paranthesis correctly... (operator precedence, `and` before `or`)

Comment: `..and (eventidname LIKE '%webinar%' OR eventidname  LIKE  '%network%')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining "LIKE" and "IN" for SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865353/combining-like-and-in-for-sql-server)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

please try

```
... where sev.SNAP_EventStart >= '2015-04-01'
    and (eventidname like '%webinar%' or eventidname like '%network%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    table t INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  '%webinar%' Col
            UNION SELECT '%network%' col
        ) a ON t.COLUMN LIKE a.Col
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

`select 
    ,fsa.eventid
    ,sev.EventStart
    from
    event sev
    on 
    sev.eventId = fsa.eventid
    where sev.SNAP_EventStart >= '2015-04-01'
    and

    (
        Patindex('%webinar%', eventidname) = 1
        OR Patindex('%network%', eventidname) = 1
    )`