# "Like" condition in multiple values seperated by comma in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a sample query with the output in the screenshot below.

Sample Query and its Output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGdPT.png)

But I am supposed to get the same ouput with the query written in a single line using "Like" condition. I have tried my best and also attached what I have tried below:

Screenshot of Query Tried

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odTT3.png)

Comment: Use the `IN` operator instead.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Its like based search, will IN work ?

Comment: @Geetha  Did you ever get a chance to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865353/combining-like-and-in-for-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure what the parameters of your assignment are, but this will work to produce the same results.

```
Select *
From City
Where City like '%Salem%' 
or City like '%Chennai%' 
or City like '%Bangalore%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try With IN OPERATOR :-

```
Select *
From City
Where City IN ('Salem','Chennai','Banglore')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    VALUES ('Chennai')
        ,('Chennai,Bangalore')
        ,('Bangalore')
        ,('Bangalore,Salem')
        ,('Salem')
        ,('Covai,Salem')
        ,('Chennai,Covai,Salem')
        ,('Chennai,Bangalore,Covai,Salem')
    ) T(city)
WHERE city LIKE '%'
    OR city LIKE '%' + REPLACE(city, ',', '%')+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use multiple `OR` conditions as mentioned in one of the answers or you can do this

```
WITH data as
(
SELECT'%Salem%' as city
union all
SELECT'%Chennai%' as city
union all
SELECT'%Bangalore%' as city
)

SELECT DISTINCT c.* FROM city c INNER JOIN data d ON c.city like d.city
```

Comment: Almost the same, consider the fictive city 'Salem Bangalore'. (Or York vs New York.)

Comment: I have added `DISTINCT` now it won't return any duplicate rows, If that's what you were pointing out. @jarlh