# Doctrine 2: Check if string element is contained in string

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

The user on my website can have multiple roles. I would like to display products to the user depending on the role he has.

My products table has the field "roles" with string as data type and it can have *one or more* roles, separated by comma. Example for a product:

```
product_roles: 'role2, role5, role6'
```

My variable `$rolesLoggedInUser` contains the following array:

```
$rolesLoggedInUser = ['role3', 'role5', 'role7']
```

In my repository, I have the following query:

```
$qb->select('p')
   ->where('p.roles IN :rolesLoggedInUser')
   ->setParameter('rolesLoggedInUser', $rolesLoggedInUser)
```

My goal is that my query returns all data rows in which the field `product_roles` contains **one or more roles** contained in `$rolesLoggedInUser`. How do I achieve that?

Comment: By concatenating the product roles into a single string you have made your life very difficult. Refactor your db so that a table product_roles has product_id(int with foreign key) & role(string). After that you can use a sub query.

Comment: Yep.  What @NeilMasters said.  It's possible to do something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865353/combining-like-and-in-for-sql-server but a product role table will be much more performant and less hassle.  And make sure you put parens around :rolesLoggedInUser