# Is there an easier way to combine multiple criteria using 'like'

Tags: sql, union, sql-like

I was able to create my query by using `Union`. However I am wondering if there is an easier way to create the same results? I've tried using `in ('abc%','def%')` and `like ('abc%','def%')` however I get a syntax error near the comma separating the two words in parenthesis.

Here is what I have so far...

```
select distinct a.case,a.person,a.personid,b.plans,a.code,a.action,cast(a.datea as date) as datea,cast(a.dateb as date) as dateb,a.updatecode
from table(nolock) a

inner join table(nolock) b on a.column=b.column

where updatecode = 'invalid'

and code like ('pr%') and datea >= '2016-09-16' and len (b.plans) = 16

union

select distinct a.case,a.person,a.personid,b.plans,a.code,a.action,cast(a.datea as date) as datea,cast(a.dateb as date) as dateb,a.updatecode

from table(nolock) a

inner join table(nolock) b on a.column=b.column

where updatecode = 'invalid'

and code like ('sea%') and datea >= '2016-09-16' and len (b.plans) = 16
```

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: `where updatecode = 'invalid'
and (code like ('pr%') OR code like ('sea%'))
and datea >= '2016-09-16' 
and len (b.plans) = 16`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining "LIKE" and "IN" for SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865353/combining-like-and-in-for-sql-server)

Comment: No need to combine select distinct and union.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
(code like 'pr%' OR code like 'sea%')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a good, clean-looking solution, but you can string multiple `like` queries with `or`, as in:

```
 select * from config.devices where displayname like 'Im%' or displayname like 'In%'
```

This will return all results that start with either "Im" or "In".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select distinct a.case,a.person,a.personid,b.plans,a.code,a.action,cast(a.datea as date) as datea,cast(a.dateb as date) as dateb,a.updatecode
from table(nolock) a
inner join table(nolock) b on a.column=b.column
where updatecode = 'invalid'
and (code like ('pr%') OR code like ('sea%'))
and datea >= '2016-09-16' 
and len (b.plans) = 16
```