# how to use LIKE instead of IN with multiple values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I want to replace In with Like to make the query work.

```
SELECT  
    1 AS coddit, COD_CAT AS cam_cod, DES_CAT AS cam_desc, 
    LIVELLO_CAT AS livello, COD_CAT_PADRE AS cat_padre,
    COD_L1, COD_L2, COD_L3, COD_L4, COD_L5, COD_L6
FROM
    dbo.CLASS_ART
WHERE
    1=1 
    AND TIPO_CLASS = 16 --B2B
    AND LIVELLO_CAT = '0'
    AND COD_CAT IN (SELECT DISTINCT CAT_MERCE.COD_CAT
                    FROM ART_LIST_PREZZI 
                    INNER JOIN ART_ANA ON ART_LIST_PREZZI.COD_ART = ART_ANA.COD_ART
                    INNER JOIN CAT_MERCE ON ART_ANA.COD_CAT = CAT_MERCE.COD_CAT
                                         AND ART_LIST_PREZZI.COD_LIST = 'EXPORT_002')
```

The comparison I would like to do with LIKE otherwise the query doesn't work well
the subquery returns more than one value and it is correct but if I use Like instead of IN I have this error message:

> Query return more than 1 values

Comment: you sure thats the query causing that error? as `COD_CAT IN (select DISTINCT CAT_MERCE.COD_CAT
from ART_LIST_PREZZI .. )` should work just fine ..

Comment: the query works but i want to remove In and put Like

Comment: ... also you most likely tagged the wrong RDMS .. As `dbo` usage most likely suggests you are using SQL Server (MSSQL) and not MySQL ..

Comment: An "IN subquery" may return many rows.

Comment: Any views involved?

Comment: for the comparison I need LIKE instead of IN

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) then we can start giving solid answers..

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865353/combining-like-and-in-for-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `LIKE` against a subquery that returns multiple records won't work. A solution would be to turn the `IN` condition to an `EXISTS` condition, like:

```
and exists (
    select 1
    from  ART_LIST_PREZZI 
    inner join ART_ANA 
        on ART_LIST_PREZZI.COD_ART = ART_ANA.COD_ART
    inner join CAT_MERCE 
        on ART_ANA.COD_CAT = CAT_MERCE.COD_CAT 
        and ART_LIST_PREZZI.COD_LIST = 'EXPORT_002'
    where COD_CAT like '%' + CAT_MERCE.COD_CAT + '%'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like has to be compared to a single string, so you need to set all your ids on a single string. You can do that using the for xml clause.

```
(SELECT DISTINCT CAST(CAT_MERCE.COD_CAT AS VARCHAR(32))
 FROM ART_LIST_PREZZI 
      INNER JOIN ART_ANA ON ART_LIST_PREZZI.COD_ART = ART_ANA.COD_ART
      INNER JOIN CAT_MERCE ON ART_ANA.COD_CAT = CAT_MERCE.COD_CAT
                              AND ART_LIST_PREZZI.COD_LIST = 'EXPORT_002'
 FOR XML PATH(''))
```

Now I would delimite your ids by commas, so you don't find false positives, and compare it using like.

```
AND
  (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST(CAT_MERCE.COD_CAT AS VARCHAR(32)) + ','
   FROM ART_LIST_PREZZI 
        INNER JOIN ART_ANA ON ART_LIST_PREZZI.COD_ART = ART_ANA.COD_ART
        INNER JOIN CAT_MERCE ON ART_ANA.COD_CAT = CAT_MERCE.COD_CAT
                                AND ART_LIST_PREZZI.COD_LIST = 'EXPORT_002'
   FOR XML PATH('')) LIKE '%,' + COD_CAT + ',%'
```

This would work, and you would have changed your IN operator with a LIKE operator, but I don't see the point of it, its performance would be worse than your original query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM ART_LIST_PREZZI LP JOIN
             ART_ANA A
             ON LP.COD_ART = A.COD_ART JOIN
             CAT_MERCE M
             ON A.COD_CAT = M.COD_CAT AND
                LP.COD_LIST = 'EXPORT_002' AND
                CLASS_ART.COD_CAT LIKE M.COD_CAT
       )
```

I assume that the logic you actually want uses wildcards:

```
                CLASS_ART.COD_CAT LIKE CONCAT('%', M.COD_CAT, '%')
```

If so, it suggests an issue with the data model.  Why would two columns with the same name (`COD_CAT`) need to be joined using `LIKE` instead of `=`.