# How to check for multiple patterns in Google BigQuery SQL? (LIKE + IN)

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-like

So I have to search for a bunch of names in a BigQuery table which I collect periodically in another dataset. The dataset is too large at this point containing almost ~60k names and I no longer can do

```
SELECT * FROM base.table WHERE name LIKE '%name1%' OR name LIKE '%name2%.....
```

As I tried it using a python script with:

```
SELECT * FROM base.table WHERE name LIKE({' OR '.join([f'ulv4.full_name LIKE %{name}%' for name in names])})
```

But the character limit for query exceeds for this many names. I tried looking at solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14125755/15649106) and other answers to the same question but no answer seems to work for BigQuery Standard SQL. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep the names in another table and then join to it:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM base.table t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM other.table t2
              WHERE t1.name LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.name, '%'));
```

Then, any record in the `base.table` would only match if it contains some substring name from the other table.

Comment: Hey it passes the checks for query but upon running it throws error: `Scalar subquery produced more than one element`

Comment: @Hamza Try the updated version using exists logic.

Comment: Updated logic further throws error: `LEFT SEMI JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.`

Comment: I'm stumped.  I'll leave this answer up until someone else can give you a working solution.  BigQuery is chock full of quirks.