# SQL Query Dynamically Create Multiple LIKE/OR Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create the answer

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE column LIKE 'Text%' 
   OR column LIKE 'Hello%' 
   OR column LIKE 'That%'
```

in below link:

[Combining "LIKE" and "IN" for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865353/combining-like-and-in-for-sql-serve)

The problem is, in my example the values in the answer 'Text', 'Hello' and 'That' are not hard coded, they are populated from an application multi-select control and can be `NULL` value or a comma-separated string like this :

```
DECLARE @String_With_Commas nvarchar(255);
SET @String_With_Commas = N'Mercedes,BMW,Audi,Tesla,Land Rover';
```

I have tried below code, but it didn't work :

```
DECLARE @SearchString = CONCAT('''',REPLACE(@String_With_Commas, N',', N'%'' OR column LIKE '''));
```

And use it like :

```
WHERE column LIKE @SearchString + '%' + ''''
```

Comment: If you didn't use a comma separated list in a string but a proper table variable, you could easily use a join.

Comment: It can be a Run time-compiled Transact-SQL statement, in these cases, [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is one way to do it. Just be aware that these statements can expose applications to malicious attacks.

Comment: The comma-separated string is coming as a multiple-filter selection form control on a web form. So basically user makes multiple selections on the form, I catch them as comma-separated-string and want to return the result by applying LIKE clause to all these values

Comment: Most languages support table type parameters, @rick_87394 . I suspect you could change your application to use one instead.

Comment: @Larnu, should I try to use table type parameters or try your answer? By the way, I am running the stored procedures from a .NET application with Dapper

Comment: The solutions with a table type parameter would likely be identical, @rick_87394 , apart from you would use your table type parameter instead of `STRING_SPLIT`. The advantage, however, is that you don't need to rely on the function, and won't have to *assume* your values don't have a delimiter in their actual value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Assuming* you are using a fully supported version of SQL Server, a couple ideas:

`JOIN` to `STRING_SPLIT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@YourVariable,',') SS ON YT.YourColumn LIKE SS.[value] + '%';
```

This will, however, return multiple rows if there can be multiple matches.

Use an `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM STRING_SPLIT(@YourVariable,',') SS
              WHERE YT.YourColumn LIKE SS.[value] + '%');
```

This won't return the same row twice, if there are multiple matches.

---

From the comments on this answer, the requirement that the parameter be `NULL`able was omitted in the question. I would therefore suggest you use the `EXISTS` solution:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM STRING_SPLIT(@YourVariable,',') SS
              WHERE YT.YourColumn LIKE SS.[value] + '%')
   OR @YourVariable IS NULL
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: This works when there is a value in the `@YourVariable`, but when `@YourVariable` is '' (NULL), it doesn't return any values. This is one of the filters in the `WHERE` clause similar to many other filter conditions and is being used with checking `NULL` values all the time like:   `@YourVariable IS NULL OR (YT.YourColumn IN (select value from string_split(@YourVariable,',')))` which will return exact matches, but not similar ones with `LIKE`

Comment: @rick_87394 handling the parameter being `NULL` isn't even touched in your question... If that was a requirement, if should have been in your question. Though to handle it, you just need an `OR`. (Though I would recommend also then adding `RECOMPILE` to your `OPTION` clause.)

Comment: Should I use `OR` in the `JOIN` ?

Comment: I would suggest you use the `EXISTS` solution if you need to handle `NULL` parameters, @rick_87394 .

Comment: Thank you, but applying your suggestion will be a completely different solution to use `EXISTS` with `LIKE` and maybe require a different question cause I also couldn't figure out how to do that

Comment: I've updated the answer to meet your omitted requirement, @rick_87394 , however, if that doesn't answer then you'll need to ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and ensure you explicitly explain what the problem you are *really* trying to solve is and not omit requirements.

Comment: Ok sorry for the omitted requirement, I have now added it to the question and the answer is working as expected, thank you